# How to throw an exception and continue looping (or how to throw many exception from one loop)

Tags: c#, exception

I have two method and for me need to generate exception from one to another some like this

```
public void Method1()
{ 
    try
    {  
        Method2(1);
    }
    catch(Exception e )
    {
        SendEmail (/* some message */)
    }
}

public IEnumerable<int> Method2(int id)
{
    foreach (var i in col)
    {
        try
        { 
            /*Do some stuff*/ 
            yield return i 
        }
       catch
       {
           /* delegate this exception to Method1 and continue foreach loop */
       }            
    }
 }
```

How to delegate exception from Method 2 to Method 1 and continue foreach loop in method 2

**UPD:**

And how about

for example : Method 1 -> Method3 -> Method2 -> method 2 return exception in method 1

**UPD2: to UPD**

```
   /*Call*/
        var i = new List<int>() {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 9};
        Calc(i, SendMessage);


   public static void SendMessage(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    public static double Calc(List<int> list, Action<Exception> callback)
    {
        var a = 0.00;
        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            try
            {
                a = Calc1(i);/*if here (double)7 / i it's just works but in how to include in method*/
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                callback(ex);
            }
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static double Calc1(int i)
    {
        var a = 0.00;
        a = (double)7 / i;
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: The whole point of throwing an exception is to stop the command flow and return to the caller. If you want to send information to the caller **without** stopping the command flow (i.e. a loop) then you should send an event, send a message, etc.

Comment: What would you expect to happen if somebody called Method2 directly without going via Method1?

Comment: why not just call SendEmail in the catch block in Method2 or is this a simplified example?

Comment: May be this and just for catching and combine exception in one place. And if method 2 would be caled from other place

Comment: Why are you using `yield return` at all? The `IE<int>` returned from `Method2` seems ignored. If it is not, what are you doing with it later? What should happen with the 'rest' of that `IE<int>` when  an exception happen at one or two items?

Comment: and if for example we will have chain call -> Method 1 call Method 3 and after that method3 call method 2 and after need to catch exception in method 1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. You can't have `yield return` inside try/catch.
2. You can do it this way if you really want to do it but I don't really recommend this approach. Exceptions should be handled when and where they are thrown or should be re-thrown in my opinion.

   ```
   public void Method1()
   {
       Method2(1, ex => SendEmail(ex));
   }

   public IEnumerable<int> Method2(int id, Action<Exception> callback)
   {
       foreach (var i in new List<int>())
       {
           try
           {
               /*Do some stuff*/
           }
           catch(Exception ex)
           {
               callback(ex);
           }

           yield return i;
       }
   }

   private void SendEmail(Exception ex)
   {
       // blah
   }
   ```

Comment: Ok how about Method3 which call method2 and catch all in method 1

Comment: Pass in the callback from method2 to method3 and do the same.

Comment: Do you mean each method should have delegate parameter?

Comment: I have mentioned that I really discourage this approach. Having said that, if you really must propagate the exceptions (without re-throwing), I'm not sure if there's another way other than either using AggregateException, saving it in a List<Exception>() that's passed around or calling a callback by delegates. In general, this is not a good approach and if it was me, I would much rather deal with them where I catch them or re-throwing them. Exceptions aren't meant to be passed around like this in the .NET world.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Once an exception is thrown back to `Method1`, `Method2` cannot continue.

What you can do, however, is give `Method2` a callback function that handles the exceptions.

```
public IEnumerable<int> Method2(Func<Exception, bool> handler)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!handler(ex))
                throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Now `Method1` can pass a function that gets an exception, and returns whether it has handled that exception. If it has, the loop continues.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the other answers, you can't "`yield throw`" an exception.  One workaround would be to catch the exception and return an object that includes it.  (e.g. a `KeyValuePair<int, Exception>`)

```
public void Method1()
{
    foreach(var i in Method2(1))
    {
        if (i.Value == null)
        {
            // No Exception Thrown
        }
        else
        {
            // Exception Thrown
            SendEmail(); // Send a message
        }
    }       
}

public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, Exception>> Method2(int id)
{
    List<int> col = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    Exception exception;

    foreach (var i in col)
    {
        exception = null;
        try
        { 
            if ((i % 2) == 1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Test" + i);
            }
            /*Do some stuff*/
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
        }

        yield return new KeyValuePair<int, Exception>(i, exception);
    }
}
```